# App to fit to other Screen sizes

Tags: android

I have finished creating an app but after taking a look on other phones I have seen that the content of the app does not fit or has moved on the screen from what I set it out as on Eclipse.

So I was looking around on StackOverflow to find out how to do this and I found this short code.

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
 switch(displayMetrics.densityDpi){ 
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW: 
    // layout for small sized devices.
    break; 
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM: 
    // layout for medium-sized devices.
    break; 
 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
    // layout for big-sized devices.
    break; 
 }
```

I am a little confused on where to put this and what to do, I would guess that this code would go into the pages XML files? and in the //layout for xxxxx would go the xml code for that size phone.

But how do I know how to space the app out without having lots of phone to test them on? just keep using the inbuilt emulator to test on the smallest screen size the medium and the large screen size till it all fits?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172502/android-maintain-same-proportion-for-all-different-screen-sizes-and-resolution

Comment: [Supporting Different Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a single layout using WRAP_CONTENT attribute and use different type of images for all resolutions like drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi etc. the key is to use different drawables in proportion and let the OS calculate things and draw the layout for you.

Also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172502/android-maintain-same-proportion-for-all-different-screen-sizes-and-resolution).

Comment: So if the images are the right size then it will all fit? I have an image with text ontop of it the issue is the text moves around on large or smaller phones.

Comment: Yes, if you have the right sized images they will all fit.Please elaborate on your text on top image issue.